# Removal of heat from a closed system using electricity

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

I was thinking this morning about how heat could be removed from a system in such a way that it is stored for future use. My ideas are a form of thermo-electric system that converts  heat into electricity which can be stored in batteries and capacitors. My question is, is it possible to use electricity as a medium to remove heat from a system? Using or generating the electricity is irrelevant, as long as more heat isn't generated. My goal is to remove heat without generating more heat.

Comment: You mean... like in power plants?

Comment: More large scale. As in, for example, using solar energy to remove heat from the earth's atmosphere, or using heat to generate electricity in such a way that the heat is removed from the system; in other words, removing heat without shunting it to another location in the same system.

Comment: The two answers both come with the caveat that you can't violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics, but it really seems like you *are* trying to violate it. Take this to heart: you can't just turn absolute heat into electricity or any other material/substance/condition that could possibly be used to do work. You can only tap into heat *differences*; i.e. you can only cool an object by moving its heat (and then some) somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest existing solution to what you're looking for is probably [Peltier cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling).

Of course Peltier coolers don't break the Second Law of Thermodynamics either: they are heat pumps, with a cold sink and a hot sink.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not trying to violate the second law of thermodynamics, yes. There are thermo-electric effects where a voltage can be generated from a temperature difference. This mechanism isn't really considered efficient though. Thermodynamically, the situation isn't too different from a regular power plant anyways, so it's never used for large scale power production.

To give you a better idea of why this isn't practical, the physicist Nicolas Carnot effectively solved your problem in the 1800's through the invention of a Carnot engine, which is provably the most efficient way to convert heat into useful energy. To do so, it's necessary to have a temperature difference between two points. As heat moves between the two points, it's possible to "capture" some of it as useful energy. This is exactly how a power plant, or any device that converts heat to useful energy works.

If you're interested in just "capturing" the heat itself, the energy used to capture the heat will always be more than the energy captured. So you'd just be generating heat.